# Trying to load static CSS file gives 404 in Vue JS app

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am working on a Vue JS app (version 2.5.17) using the webpack-simple project time, and I am trying to load a static css file in my main App component.

I have the file in:

```
src/static/reset.css
```

Then in my main app component template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/reset.css">
```

I am serving using `npm run dev`

However the CSS file returns a 404 error, and I can confirm by trying to access: `http://localhost:8080/static/reset.css`

My directory structure:

```
C:.
|   .babelrc
|   index.html
|   output.doc
|   package-lock.json
|   package.json
|   README.md
|   webpack.config.js
|                
\---src
    |   App.vue
    |   main.js
    |   routes.js
    |   
    +---assets
    |   |   logo.png
    |   |   
    |   \---css
    +---components
    |   |   Home.vue
    +---static
    |       reset.css
    |       
    \---store
        |   store.js
        |   
        \---modules
                recipe.js
```

Comment: can you share you directory structure?

Comment: Edited my post to include directory structure

Answer (score 1):

You can put your css file in the `assets/css` folder and then import it in `main.js` by doing `import '@/assets/css/reset.css'`. Check out [How the hell can i include a css file](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/604) on GitHub for many other varieties.